# LARAVEL: Como validar un campo que debe ser una fecha posterior a la actual y que no debe superar los 9 meses a partir de esa fecha actual

Tags: php, laravel, date, validación

en laravel estoy haciendo un registro de inscripción en donde tengo que validar un campo de "fecha probable de parto"

Necesito que sea una fecha futura a la actual, en donde usé la regla after_or_equal:today, pero también necesito validar que sea una fecha que no supere los 9 meses en adelante a partir de la fecha actual, que regla puedo usar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podés utilizar la libería Carbon;

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class DateController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $currentDateTime = Carbon::now();
        $newDateTime = Carbon::now()->addMonths(9);

        print_r($currentDateTime);
        print_r($newDateTime);
    }
}
```

Y así como tienes la regla after_or_equal, tienes la regla before_or_equal,  y allí lo puedes evaluar contra la fecha calculada.